# Flutter build.gradle trouble

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, build.gradle

I am currently starting Flutter Blue, a Bluetooth plugin for Flutter. I imported the example -> android -> app folder into Android studio.

However, when I am trying to build and run the code, I get the error: "Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file. "

I googled around for a solution and added the flutter SDK path into the local.properties file but that hasn't remedied the issue yet. 
flutter.sdk=/Users/me/Applications/flutter

I suspect that I am just not using Android Studio or importing the files/code correctly. I am able to compile and run Flutter's default demo app (click-counter) without any issues, so I'm fairly certain Flutter & Android Studio was installed and set up correctly.

My intuition was that the build.gradle could be directly run akin to an APK by Android Studio's device emulator. Any suggestions?

Thanks! https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/tree/master/example/android

Comment: Can you add the output for flutter doctor ?

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 ..., locale
    en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: The flutter doctor looks fine... Perhaps you need to update the flutter SDK from CLI's perspective.... Did you install the flutter and dart plugins? Also does the hello world flutter app work

Comment: I think I figured out what was causing the issue, thanks!

Comment: Nice what was it? Perhaps post the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not importing the example correctly into Android Studio. The correct way is to drag and drop the project files into AS.